# Need an online freely available Anaphorically Annotated Corpus of English Language for Identification of Discourse Units

Tags: computational-linguistics, corpora, discourse-analysis, anaphora

I'm in need of a freely available corpus of English language (which may contain text of any genre) but has to be annotated anaphoriacally i-e. Anaphora resolution should have been performed already.

Based on my googling I came up with some results such as BASHI and ARRAU but ARRAU is a paid resource. Any relevant help / resources / links would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This one was just released a couple months ago and is available for download.
https://github.com/synapse-developpement/Discovery

If the anaphoric references are not to your liking, run the Hugging Face Neural CoRef classifier over the dataset. https://huggingface.co/coref/

Comment: I think I've found exactly what I was looking for. Name of that resource is Phrase Detectives Corpus. It has two versions and freely available.